# Determinant of hessian matrix of a grayscale image is too small in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, hessian

I am trying to find determinant of hessian matrix of a `50x50` grayscale image. Determinant of matrix I am getting is a very small value i.e `4.7612e-134`. I think I am missing something. My code is below. Thanks

```
 % computing second derivatives in each direction first

 [gx, gy] = gradient(double(sliceOfImageK2));

 [gxx, gxy] = gradient(gx);

 [gyx, gyy] = gradient(gy);

 hessianMatrix = [gxx gxy; gxy gyy];

 determinantHessianMatrix = det(hessianMatrix)
```

Comment: might be a typo but shouldn't it be `gyx` instead of `gxy` at location `[2,1]`? I have no idea if it will change anything sorry

Comment: gyx and gxy have same values so it doesn't make ant difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should assemble a `100x100` matrix if you want to call it Hessian. Assemble instead a `2x2` matrix per each of the `50x50` (2500) pixels where you are sampling your derivatives.

These are the 2500 hessians, expressed in a `2500x4` matrix:

```
H = [gxx(:) gxy(:) gyx(:) gyy(:)]
```

Here expressed as 2500 `2x2` matrices:

```
H_ = reshape(H', 2, 2, length(H))
```

And these are the determinants of each `2x2` matrix:

```
D = H(:,1).*H(:,4) - H(:,2).*H(:,3)
```

Here as a `50x50` matrix with the determinant of the Hessian at each pixel, if that is what you are after:

```
reshape(D, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. After running above commands I got H(625 x 4), H_(2 x 2 x 625) and D(625 x 1). I don't want to reshape it into 50 x 50 rather I want a single value determinant. Thanks